# Android listview with check box

Tags: android

In my case i have two text view and one check box in listview. I am using ArrayAdapter class to set the data in textviews.

When i select any check box and scroll in list view some check boxes are automatically selected.I am not getting why is this happening below is my code please look the code and give the solution to solve this out.

```
public class Contacts_NumberActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    String nameList[] = { "U", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H",
            "I", "J", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q" }, numberList[] = { "1",
            "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4",
            "5", "6", "7" };
    ListView contactList;
    boolean[] checked;
    ContactHolder holder = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        contactList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);

        contactList.setAdapter(new ContactAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item,
                nameList, numberList));

    }

    public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        String data[] = null;
        String data1[] = null;

        public ContactAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                String[] data, String[] data1) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
            this.data1 = data1;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context)
                        .getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

                holder = new ContactHolder();
                holder.name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.number = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.number);
                holder.chkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                holder.chkbox
                        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(
                                    CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                                holder.chkbox.setChecked(isChecked);
                                System.out.println("Checked possition= "
                                        + isChecked);
                            }

                        });

                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ContactHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText(data[position]);
            holder.number.setText(data1[position]);

            return row;
        }

        public class ContactHolder {
            TextView name, number;
            CheckBox chkbox;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this Link.it may helpfull.. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: i guess problem with printing your listview.please check your listview it may have data repeat,that's why you are feeling like automatically checkbox getting selected.check and let me know that

Comment: this is happening when i clicked any check box and scroll the list the below check boxes are also checked.

Comment: check below links it may help you http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/11/05/of-rubber-stamps-and-checkboxes-why-your-listview-is-broken/

Answer (score 0):

your code has no problem but the problem is because of ArrayAdapter's getView function
which is calling in manner that to reinitialize and reuse the unfocused rows of list for that you are using convert view check which is causing paging as if in screen you check first check box then all screens in paging get the first check box checked,

to get resolved from this you should use layout instead of list view using adapter here is an hint may help you

```
LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(this);
parent.setOrientation(VERTICAL);
parent.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(list_width,list_height);

for(number of rows in your list)
{
LinearLayout row= new LinearLayout(this);
row.setOrientation(Horizontal);
row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(row_width,row_height);

TextView text= new TextView (this);
text.setText("your text");
text.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(text_width,text_height);
row.addView(text);
.
.//other view you want to add as check box etc
.
.
parent.AddView(row);
}

this.addView(parent);

hope this will help you
```

note:but in case you have a large number of rows it may cause memory issues